# Scrolling to item in GridView [ANDROID]

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have a GridView in a fragment to which I'm passing a position from its parent activity. I want the GridView to be scrolled down enough so I can see the item on provided position. So far I have tried:

```
    mGridView.setSelection(((ImageDetailActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentPage());
    mGridView.requestFocus();
```

And

```
    mGridView.setSelection(((ImageDetailActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentPage());
    mGridView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Both don't seem to work. Is it possible?

Comment: UPDATE - found a solution:

mGridView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mGridView.setSelection(((ImageDetailActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentPage());
    }
});

Comment: you need something like that? gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int index)